# How to get clipboard content in GTK3 (GI) and Python 3 on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, pygtk, gtk3

In Python 2, with what's installed in my machine (Ubuntu 12.10), I can do

```
import gtk
cb = gtk.clipboard_get()
content = cb.wait_for_text()
```

to get the text from the clipboard.

In Python3, however, I was supposed to do the same with the Gtk.Clipboard() object, but I get thrown some errors that seem to be related to widgets and things like that, but my application has no GUI and is not supposed to. Am I on the right track?

```
>>> from gi.repository import Gtk
>>> cb = Gtk.Clipboard()
>>> content = cb.wait_for_text()
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py:47: Warning: g_object_get_data: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)

(.:10935): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_display_get_default_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(.:10935): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_invisible_new_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py:47: Warning: invalid (NULL) pointer instance
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py:47: Warning: g_signal_connect_data: assertion `G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)

(.:10935): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_add_events: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py:47: Warning: g_object_set_data: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/types.py:47: Warning: g_object_set_qdata: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
  return info.invoke(*args, **kwargs)

(.:10935): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_display_get_default_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed

(.:10935): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_invisible_new_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(.:10935): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_add_events: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(.:10935): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_window: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(.:10935): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_selection_convert: assertion `GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Comment: Considered posting this as a bug to Ubuntu or Gnome?

Comment: Hello. I began to wonder if it's a bug, but I wanted to make sure first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't just dealing with Python 2 and Python 3 -- in fact that is irrelevant in this case. What *does* matter is that the first example is using PyGTK which is GTK2 and the second is using PyGObject which is GTK3.

Since GTK3 is using [gobject introspection](https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection) with Python, some of the magic that was manually maintained in PyGTK is not there. If you look at the [C API for the Clipboard](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-Clipboards.html) you will see that `Gtk.Clipboard.get()` has a required argument to identify the clipboard. This is explained in the reference for [gtk_clipboard_get_for_display()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-Clipboards.html#gtk-clipboard-get-for-display).

To make a long story short, the correct code in GTK3 is more like this:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
cb = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
content = cb.wait_for_text()
```

Comment: Hello, Micah. I'm aware of the parameter to the function, but I'm basing myself on some examples I saw on the internet (which are supposed to work). Not only examples in Python, but in Vala. Anyway, Gtk.Clipboard(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD) throws a type error:

Comment: >>> cb = Gtk.Clipboard(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant `cb = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)`. There is no constructor as there is no corresponding `gtk_clipboard_new`.