# python PyGObject :how to save clipboard as image

Tags: python-3.x, pygobject

I have a snapshot tool in linux, i copied the image there into clipboard

now i want to save. I am not able to understand how to complete the steps. I wrote what i can understand till

I want to do it using pyObject

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)
```

after this how to save image to  `/home/user/filename.png`

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207897/how-to-get-clipboard-content-in-gtk3-gi-and-python-3-on-ubuntu) post on SO, the call to `Gtk.Clipboard.get()` requires an argument to identify the clipboard. Therefore, to get an image from the clipboard, you'd have to call `wait_for_image()`. This will return a pixbuf object.

In order to save this pixbuf object as a `.png` to disk, you could convert it to a Pillow image object using the `pixbuf2image(pix)` function that was taken from [this](https://gist.github.com/mozbugbox/10cd35b2872628246140) GitHub Gist from user mozbugbox. The Pillow image object then has a `save()` method to save the image directly to disk.

```py
import gi
from PIL import Image as PILImage
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

def pixbuf2image(pix):
    """Convert gdkpixbuf to PIL image"""
    data = pix.get_pixels()
    w = pix.props.width
    h = pix.props.height
    stride = pix.props.rowstride
    mode = "RGB"
    if pix.props.has_alpha == True:
        mode = "RGBA"
    im = PILImage.frombytes(mode, (w, h), data, "raw", mode, stride)
    return im

clipboard = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD)

pixbuf_img = Gtk.Clipboard.get(Gdk.SELECTION_CLIPBOARD).wait_for_image()
pil_image = pixbuf2image(pixbuf_img)
pil_image.save(str(imgpath))
```